# How to adjust menu color in Sublime Text

Tags: settings, sublimetext4

After downloading a Sublime update months ago, the menu text all turned white, along with the backgrounds, making them virtually unreadable. What I've looked up on fixing this, seems to do everything but change the background color of the menus, so regardless of what the editor field looks like, the menus are still unreadable. I'm curious if anyone knows how to adjust this feature.

[image]

Comment: You have two `"theme"` entries in your user preferences. Try getting rid of one of them.

Comment: Also, have you created any theme overrides in your `Packages/User` folder?

Comment: No, I basically leave the settings as default.

Comment: Sublime Text 3 has no theme mechanism for changing the menu rendering like this; what build are you running?

Comment: Currently running Build 4113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is the result of custom themes on Windows, so sadly there is no "fix" with Sublime.

Go to your Windows Settings > Theme and choose the one that just says "Windows", which should be a default blue color. Click on that and give it a minute to change everything. Then go back and double check Sublime. It's a bummer there isn't another way, but this should resolve it.